# Ethernet in Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work for a specific network

Tags: ethernet

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. My Ethernet works perfectly well in my office but at home it doesn't at all. It never gets connected. Mean while other machines are connected.

And my WiFi too is not stable, it connects and disconnects ie on and off.
So please if anyone can be of help because its becomes difficult for me to work on stuffs at home.